# jquery list element with opacity on hover.

Tags: jquery, menu, opacity

I'm trying to build a simply menu with images where the selected has a `opacity:1` and the  other `li` have `opacity:0.4` .

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

eg here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/161/

Comment: You had an extra `})` at the bottom throwing an error. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mdamC/164/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors which are the likely culprit.  Within your document ready function, use the following:

```
$("li").css('opacity','0.40');
$(".selected").css('opacity','1');

$('ul.showcase').on("mouseover", "li", function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
});

$('ul.showcase').on("mouseout", "li:not(.selected)", function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.4);
});
```

Note that this requires jQuery 1.7+ with it's use of the `.on()` API.  I highly suggest this though as the use of delegated events is far more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error, take off the last `});`. I don't know what your intent is but that will at least get it to parse. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/173/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in a document ready function, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ....code here....
});
```

or a simplified version:

```
$(function(){
    .....code here....
});
```

Also, you need some semicolons to close the first two opacity statements:

```
$("li").css('opacity','0.40');
$(".selected").css('opacity','1');
```

Update here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/163/

Comment: Actually, in this case you don't. jsFiddle does that for you, look over on the side, in the settings it says "onDomReady".

Comment: Assuming this code was copied from the OP's original file, it'll be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fade everything except the selected link, try this:

```
$('ul.showcase').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('li').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('li:not(".selected")').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.4);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mdamC/171/

Comment: like that I got all the Li disappeared  on hover

Comment: I need to have the li with the opacity:1 on hover, the other li's shld stay 0.4, is that possible?

Comment: Please explain better exactly what you want to happen.